# How to update 32bit app with CorePlot to work with iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I am trying to update an old 32-bit app to 64-bit so that it can run on iOS 11. I'm using Xcode 8.0 and am building with standard architecture arm64 and armv7. When I try to build the project, this error comes up:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotSymbol", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTFill", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTScatterPlot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_CPTDecimalFromString", referenced from:
      -[PenetrationPlotViewController viewDidLoad] in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGradient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTheme", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_kCPTDarkGradientTheme", referenced from:
      -[PenetrationPlotViewController viewDidLoad] in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableLineStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotRange", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
  "_CPTDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
      -[PenetrationPlotViewController viewDidLoad] in PenetrationPlotViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have the latest version of core plot downloaded from GitHub from this site: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot
and I tried the iOS application method on https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Using-Core-Plot-in-an-Application.

Does anyone know a fix to this or if I'm missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked you've built a 64-bit version of the CorePlot static library?

Comment: Are you building from source ("dependent library") or including the pre-built static library or framework? Are you using a dependency manager (CocoaPods or Carthage) to get the code or doing it manually?